# Extract zip bundle into same file

Tags: linux, zip

I want to bundle below three files and extract into the same folder.

```
files1.txt
files2.txt
files3.txt

zip -r myfiles.zip files1.txt files2.txt files3.txt
```

Output When extracting the zip:

```
files1.txt
files2.txt
files3.txt
```

Expected output:

```
myfiles/files1.txt
myfiles/files2.txt
myfiles/files3.txt
```

Comment: Do you want the archive to contain the "myfiles" subfolder, or do you want a command-line that extracts a flat zip archive into that subfolder?

Comment: When I extract the .zip file, I would expect to have the files within the main folder(myfiles)

Comment: I wasn't clear enough; can the extraction command be modified, as the current answer has, or should the archive contain the folder such that a vanilla extraction command results in a subdirectory?

Comment: use the `-d` option of `unzip`: `unzip -d myfiles myfiles.zip`

Comment: Why not `mkdir myfiles/ ; mv files*txt myfiles/ ; zip -r myfiles.zip myfiles/` ?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly you could specify a -d option:

```
unzip myfiles.zip -d myfiles
```

A directory named as the argument of the -d option will be created with the extracted files inside it.